# longpress custom items UICollectionViewCell image change

Tags: uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer, cell, uicollectionview, gestures

How can I make a cell imageview to change after longpress gesture?

With this one when I click on a cell (longpress) the 4 customized items appear but when I select one of them the app crashes. (if you remove :(Cell*)cell and cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ICUbedRED.png"]]; it works...I mean the alertView appears but of course the image doesn't change).

```
 - (void)longPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        Cell *cell = (Cell *)recognizer.view;
        [cell becomeFirstResponder];

        UIMenuItem *highDep = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"High Dependency" action:@selector(hiDep:)];
        UIMenuItem *lowDep = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Low Dependency" action:@selector(lowDep:)];
        UIMenuItem *booked = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Booked"     action:@selector(booked:)];
        UIMenuItem *free = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Free" action:@selector(free:)];

            UIMenuController *menu = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
    [menu setMenuItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:booked, highDep, lowDep, free, nil]];
        [menu setTargetRect:cell.frame inView:cell.superview];
        [menu setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES];



   }
}
```

the voids are:

```
 - (void)hiDep:(Cell*)cell
 {
    NSLog(@"Bed is HiDep");

    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ICUbedRED.png"]];




     UIAlertView *testAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"This Bed is High     Dependency"
                                                message:@""
                                               delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"       otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];



    [testAlert show];
    [testAlert release];


  }

- (void)lowDep:(Cell*)cell
 {.
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString     stringWithFormat:@"ICUbedYELLOW.png"]];
..}

 - (void)free:(Cell*)cell
 {..
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ICUbedGREEN.png"]];
.}

 - (void)booked:(Cell*)cell
 {..
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ICUbedBLUE.png"]];
.}
```

and the cell building method is:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView     cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

     static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";
    Cell *cvc = (Cell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    int i = indexPath.row%[labelArray count];
    number = i;

    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPress:)];



    [cvc addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];


    cvc.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"icubed.png"]];
    cvc.label.text =  [labelArray objectAtIndex:number];

       return cvc;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

@dottorfeelgood It is crashing for

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWi......
```

because, the object retured as param to methods like

- (void)lowDep:(Cell*)cell
  is not of Class Cell, the retured param is of class UIMenuItem. because you are clicking on menuItems not Cell.

Instead of doing what you are doing now, you can use the MenuItems and corresponding actions on UICollectionCell solution provided by UICollectionView by default. You can check this tutorial [here](http://paulsolt.com/2012/11/uicollectionview-custom-actions-and-uimenucontroller/)!

Just implement the 3 delegate methods and

```
// These methods provide support for copy/paste actions on cells.
// All three should be implemented if any are.
- (BOOL)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView shouldShowMenuForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
- (BOOL)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView canPerformAction:(SEL)action forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath withSender:(id)sender;
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView performAction:(SEL)action forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath withSender:(id)sender;
```

and set your custom menuItems needed to the sharedMenuController in ViewdidLoad.

Hope this helps, excuse my bad sentence forming.